# 1000 Mbit/s Connection but WLAN only gets 54 Mbit/s

Tags: wireless-networking

I have got the problem, that my WLAN only gives me 54Mbit/s download rate on Speedtest, but with an Ethernet connection I get almost 1000 Mbit/s. I have the Fritzbox 7490 with the 802.11ac standard. What could be the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wireless is never as fast as wired. Plus, wireless is half-duplex.

Comment: What are you measuring anyway? It can’t be a VDSL uplink. You also don’t say anything about the WiFi station, distance/obstacles between the two and what the operating system indicates. As is, this question simply cannot be answered.

Comment: Your computer/phone/tablet doesn't support 802.11ac?  54 Mbps is the limit of 802.11g and 802.11n, in the 2.4 GHz band.

Comment: @psusi That’s not true. 11n provides 150 Mbps per 20 MHz channel at 1×1 MIMO. This is true for both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz.

Comment: @DanielB, sure but MIMO requires dual antennae.

Comment: @DanielB, no, 150 MBps is the 40 MHz channel rate, which normally isn't used in the 2.4 GHz band since that is pretty much the entire band.

Comment: @psusi Ah, you’re right, sorry about that. Still, the base rate is 65 Mbps and not 54. Wouldn’t really be an improvement otherwise.

Comment: Well, the real improvement is the mimo + 40 MHz channels.  The beam forming also helps improve real performance, rather than maximum theoretical under ideal conditions ( very close range ).  Also iirc, you only get the 65 Mbps rate if you disable compatibility with 802.11b/g, so typically you're still only going to see 54 Mbps in the 2.4 GHz band.

Answer (score 0):

Check the rate settings on both the router and your client driver.

Also make sure that WMM is enabled on both ends, I've [heard](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-features/30938-dont-mess-with-wmm) that it's required for Wireless AC.

Comment: Do you know where you can enable this on a Fritzbox ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested your WLAN speed only? Check at what speed your client wireless adapter connects to Fritzbox. If you use windows 7 or later this will be shown in Connection Status window.

If that says 54 then either it's max your adapter can do or - as sanitybit suggested - you need WMM enabled.